# Automate webbrowser

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a dedicated web browser for my work with some buttons which can automate tasks for me. The script I found is like below, but I'm struggling with the piece that would enter text in de search field and then hit the button. (This is a test piece ofcourse)

Does anyone know how to automate this, using the `pyqt5` example found?
Something like:

```py
self.browser.getObjectbyName("ObjName").setText("newtext")
```

I've been googling for hours but have not found any example code yet.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: Depending on your use-case, an alternative might be to use greasemonkey or tampermonkey extension to inject javascript into your real browser (eg. Chrome or Firefox).

Answer (score 2):

There are several tools in QtWebEngine to perform automated tasks on web pages:

- Execute js script using `runJavaScript()` method.
- Use QtWebChannel to exchange information and perform tasks between python and the web page.
- Implement userscripts through QWebEngineScript.

In this case I will show a demo of how to do an automated search using the first option:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

import sys

script = """
var input = document.querySelector("body > div.L3eUgb > div.o3j99.ikrT4e.om7nvf > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.A8SBwf > div.RNNXgb > div > div.a4bIc > input")
input.value = "StackOverflow"
var form = document.querySelector("body > div.L3eUgb > div.o3j99.ikrT4e.om7nvf > form")
form.submit()
"""


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.handle_load_finished)
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

    def handle_load_finished(self, ok):
        if ok:
            if self.browser.url() == QUrl("https://www.google.com/"):
                self.browser.page().runJavaScript(script)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tought it would be easier. I'm not familiar with javascript but I'll give it a go and see where it ends when I get home.